# Edit pdf embedded in the browser and save the pdf directly to server

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have this workflow.

1. Load a pdf containing form fields into the browser (pdf in iframe or div).
2. A user fills it out
3. A user click 'Submit' button (in another div) to save the pdf.

What I would like to do in #3 is to collect all the data associated with the form fields and save the data to the database table.  I don't want a user to save the pdf to his/her local computer and upload it to the server. I would like to make it more user-friendly.

I am going to use Java/JSP/Servlet in the server-side. I looked into the itext which seems to be popular/well-known for handling a pdf file, but itext seems to be used for generating/editing a pdf, but I am not sure if there is any way to have a feature being able to edit a pdf embedded in the browser and save to the database.

Is there any adobe software providing some kind feature which I can inject some kind of script which can capture a user's submit?  I know that PDF is not a front-end scripting language, but i am just asking.

I was going to create a HTML form which looks like this PDF and populate it into the PDF when a user clicks 'submit' button, but as I said, I would like to make it more user-friendly.

I'd appreciated if there is anybody who has seen this type of feature or has done it gives me some resources or tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption: you have an interactive PDF document with AcroForm fields similar to [submit_me.pdf](http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/submit_me.pdf):

[image]

The main difference, is that I have different buttons on the form:

- POST will post the data I fill out as if the PDF was an HTML form,
- FDF will post the data to the server in the Forms Data Format, a format that is very similar to PDF, but that only contains the data pairs, not the actual form,
- XFDF will post the data to the server in the XML Forms Data Format, which is the XML version of the Forms Data Format.
- RESET will reset all the fields to their initial value.

The [SubmitForm](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=168) example shows how the buttons were added to an existing form. Note that there are more options than the ones described in this example.

For instance:

- Instead of using the POST method, you can also use GET by tweaking some of the parameters,
- You can also submit the complete PDF (data + form) to the server, but this will only work if the end user has Adobe Acrobat as plug-in. This won't work if the plug-in is merely Adobe Reader,
- ...

To show you what to expect when you commit a form, I wrote the [ShowData](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=169) servlet. This servlet returns the bytes that are sent to the server.

In case of a POST:

```
personal.loginname=jdoe&personal.name=John+Doe&personal.password=test&personal.reason=reason&post.x=29&post.y=7
```

Note that I also defined the button in such a way that the coordinate of my click is passed to the server. You probably don't need this.

In case of FDF:

```
%FDF-1.2
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</FDF<</Fields[<</T(FDF)>><</Kids[<</T(loginname)/V(jdoe)>><</T(name)/V(John Doe)>><</T(password)/V(test)>><</T(reason)/V(Reason)>>]/T(personal)>>]/ID[<EF0089E16ED50F11CB6057A700B9046E><1205D069D1D6AE37665B6FF7EEA65414>]>>/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
trailer
<</Root 1 0 R>>
%%EOF
```

In case of XFDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve"
><f href="http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/submit_me.pdf"
/><fields
><field name="XFDF"
/><field name="personal"
><field name="loginname"
><value
>jdoe</value
></field
><field name="name"
><value
>John Doe</value
></field
><field name="password"
><value
>test</value
></field
><field name="reason"
><value
>Reason</value
></field
></field
></fields
><ids original="EF0089E16ED50F11CB6057A700B9046E" modified="1205D069D1D6AE37665B6FF7EEA65414"
/></xfdf
>
```

In an ideal world, this would be your solution. It is described in ISO-32000-1 which is the world-wide standard for PDF. However: many people started using crappy PDF viewers that do not support this functionality, so if you want to use this solution, you'll have to make sure that people use a decent PDF viewer as their browser plug-in.

Comment: @bruno lowagie ... my requirement is to edit a pdf file with some replacement of text and again save it as pdf.. I have found so many solution on this website but non of them is working as per my expectation..
Please share any code that can easily do that .. Thanx I have tried it since last 3 days but still stuck.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap PDF is not a word processing format. Maybe you're trying to do something that is impossible. In any case: you are hijacking the comment section of an old answer to post a new question. That is not done on StackOverflow.

Comment: hi @brunolowagie can you please give me link for that sample PDF file and is there any other solution if I put that button in html form.

Comment: @BhaumikThakkar That sample PDF is a simple form with some silly fields. What use could you possibly have for it? You will have to create an AcroForm with fields specific for *your* application anyway. Why don't you create such a form yourself? I really don't understand your question.

Comment: actually I am not aware about acroForm and I'm using PDFBox so is it possible with it ?

Comment: For backend implementation to get data in XFDF but I didn't found anywhere. What I did is created a TextField and PushbuttonField and set action as SUBMIT_XFDF and displayed in a HTML. now, how can I handle it in backend side.