# how to save Fillable pdf ASP.NET C#

Tags: itext

I need to save or capture user inputs that enter to fillable PDF document opened in a web browser, i am aware that we can create submit-able PDF documents using adobe acrobat pro or any other tool.but in my case i need to display PDF document in a browser which original PDF file is locate at server side.so after user fill the PDF fillable fields they need to press HTML button("Save"), then if i can capture those inputs then i could use "Itextsharp.DLL" to fill and save PDF programmatically  with a different name. is their anyway can i achieve this?.

Comment: Please download the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) and you'll find the answer to this question: [Edit pdf embedded in the browser and save the pdf directly to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113588/edit-pdf-embedded-in-the-browser-and-save-the-pdf-directly-to-server) If this doesn't answer your question because you want the PDF to be saved locally, please think again: the EULA of Adobe Reader forbids saving a filled out form locally unless the PDF is Reader-enabled.

Comment: Thanks Bruno Lowagie and I found this.This help me to create fillable pdf with submit button. http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter09&ex=SubmitForm